# How to change the order of a second row in a flex wrapper?

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

Is it possible to change the order of the items on the second row in a flexbox wrapper?

If it's possible, how?

I need to achieve this distribution -without changing the order with javascript.

```
1 2 3
6 5 4
```

First I need to change only the second row but, eventually, as in the case of smaller screens, it should affect all even rows following this criteria (examples on the right):

```
->->->         1  2  3    -     1  2
<-<-<-         6  5  4    -     4  3
->->->         7  8  9    -     5  6
<-<-<-        12 11 10    -     8  7
...
```

I prefer using flex in order to center an eventual last orphan item, but I may use a grid if that helps solving the problem.

This is an example of the basic code:

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

```css
ul,li { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; }
ul { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; }
ul li { flex-basis: calc((100% / 3) - 6px); }
```

And a codepen to play with:
https://codepen.io/romualdinho/pen/pogEOXz

Thank you!

Comment: added 2 duplicate that should cover the different cases

Comment: @TemaniAfif It didn't occur to me searching by "Snake". Thanks for pointing those answers out to me!